# Azure SQL Database Query Plan Differences

Tags: sql, azure

I have 2 Azure SQL Databases both with nearly identical data and resources. I am getting very different results for some queries.  I inspected the query plan and noticed some differences, but I am not sure how to address them.  Initially the server properties had different MaxDOP settings, so I changed those to match.  How should I proceed to debug this kind of issue?

The production server is much slower than the staging server and neither of them are under any load right now.

[image]

[image: server properties]

edit 1:

SQL Database settings / Server settings
Both are on the same SQL Server w/ standard 100 eDTUs

The databases both are in US West, w/ 50 DTU each, and 250GB sizes.

I also manually updated statistics for both tables before making these query plans in case that was the source of the error.

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed if geo-replication/failover configurations are identical for both production and staging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being that there were different statistics being used among all the different tables in the database not just the ones I was working with for some reason. This caused drastically different query plans and poor performance.  Use the code below to update all the tables statistics (uncomment the EXEC line) and do this weekly.

```sql
-- Update ALL Statistics WITH FULLSCAN
 
-- This will update all the statistics on all the tables in your database.
-- remove the comments from EXEC sp_executesql in order to have the commands actually update stats, instead of just printing them.
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
 
DECLARE updatestats CURSOR FOR
SELECT table_schema, table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
OPEN updatestats
 
DECLARE @tableSchema NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(300)
 
FETCH NEXT FROM updatestats INTO @tableSchema, @tableName
 
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
   SET @Statement = 'UPDATE STATISTICS '  + '[' + @tableSchema + ']' + '.' + '[' + @tableName + ']' + ' WITH FULLSCAN'
   PRINT @Statement -- comment this print statement to prevent it from printing whenever you are ready to execute the command below.
  --EXEC sp_executesql @Statement -- remove the comment on the beginning of this line to run the commands
   FETCH NEXT FROM updatestats INTO @tableSchema, @tableName
END
 
CLOSE updatestats
DEALLOCATE updatestats
GO
SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have done some of the main things to find source of issue including:

- Ensure Resources have same configurations (DB's have same #vCores/DTU's, Regions, Size, etc)
- Ran Query Execution Plan (Since the execution plans are very similar, I'm going to assume you have the exact same Indexes, Table Structures, and Data Volume between the two DB's)

If these all are the same, then you may want to monitor your LogIO, DataIO, and CPU% while you run each of the queries. You can then compare side by side to see what might be cause of strain on database. It is odd that you say both are exactly the same, yet one is much slower than the other.

I would double check configuration/settings, it could be that you have failover/backups running on production. I would use the Azure Monitor metrics to compare utilization in the two DB's, side by side, you may think nothing is running on the server, but you would be surprised. Here is an example of an Azure Monitor dashboard I created:

[image: Azure DB Metrics]

It might help if you would post your configuration/settings both for Azure SQL Server and Azure SQL DB's. But generally you are on the right track. The monitoring metrics should give you additional insight into how the DB is performing over time.

Comment: thx for the response, i added some additional info to follow up your response in the edit section.  Was that the sql database / server config info you were looking for?